# Difference between MVC and MVR?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller

I opened a NodeJS project of a friend of mine and I can see in its structure that instead of my familiar structure of models, views and controllers folders, it follows another pattern: routes, views as a folder and models as a simple .js file.

So, I searched about the MVR design pattern and I could only find [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVR) on wikipedia and [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135495/in-mvc-what-is-the-difference-between-controller-and-router) on stackexchange -and nothing useful on google-. Wikipedia says it's a variation of MVC design pattern

Could someone explain to me better what this pattern is all about?
Is it a new pattern at all or have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a MVC model you can attach routes to a controller. What I understand, MVR is a more one on one. Route and Controller are the same.

Positive thing is you will be forced to handle your routes distinctively.

On the negative side is that you can't reuse controllers before attaching them to a route.